# Youtube Video Upload speed is very slow

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We made an app which uploads a backend generated video on youtube using v3 API.
When we deploy this app on a cloud environment (Its our UAT box) the upload speed was amazing(30MB per second for a 150MB file.)

Now we deployed the same app in our production box which is a physical box in our existing infrastructure. The box has dedicated internet connection and the stats are as follows using popular internet speed test:

```
Server 1 - Download Speed ­ 541 Mbps ; Upload Speed ­ 357 Mbps
Server 2 ­ Download Speed ­ 573 Mbps; Upload Speed -  351 Mbps
```

But the video upload speed is very slow, the same video takes around 5-7 min to upload.

We also tried changing the upload chunk size from 10MB to 100MB with not much of upload performance change. Actually the 100MB sometimes take even more time with bigger chunk, guessing it fails and restarts again.

Is there a tool you can suggest we can run on our production environment to debug what can be the issue?
**Note: Its a windows server.**
I can give the information need for anything specific.

Comment: Hi, anyone can help please?

Comment: This [link](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4525858?hl=en) maybe of help to you. Most probably the upload speed is not reaching its peak because of the heavy traffic that the youtube servers are experiencing or you could also check the video format indicated in the link. You could also see this [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/hBO4cfNTP8A) which is the product forum of the issue. Hope this helps!